# What is the difference between "would visit" and "would be visiting?"

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

What is the difference between these two:

> I am busy tomorrow. If I had time, **I would visit** my grandparents.
>
> I am busy tomorrow. If I had time, **I would be visiting** my
>   grandparents.

Comment: This may help a little: [“Could be living” vs. “could live”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37002/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example is an example of "progressive" or "continuous" form: *to be* + *-ing form of verb.*

Simplifying, this form is used to indicate something happens over a length of time rather than talking about when it started, or something that only happens at a point in time.

It can also be used as a logical "stretch" when the speaker/writer wants to communicate that something is in progress or not yet complete.

Non-continuous form doesn't necessarily imply the opposite, though.

> I am busy tomorrow. If I had time, I would visit my grandparents.

Means that if the speaker/writer had time, he/she would visit his/her grandparents sometime tomorrow.  No implication as to how much of the day that would take.

> I am busy tomorrow. If I had time, I would be visiting my grandparents.

Means any of:

- If the speaker/writer had time, he/she would spend the whole day visiting his/her grandparents
- Or at least spend a significant length of time from that day visiting.
- Or the act of visiting his/her grandparents would take a significant length of time and he/she would dedicate part of the day to it.  For example, it may take several hours to travel there and/or back.

Answer (score -1):

> I am busy tomorrow. If I had time, I would visit my grandparents.
>
> I am busy tomorrow. If I had time, I would be visiting my
>   grandparents.

Both have mixed tenses which may be hampering your comprehension.

The first "I am" is present tense, singular, but is referring to an event in the future (*tomorrow*).

> I will be busy tomorrow.

Would make more sense.

The second sentences of both examples also differ in their tenses, example 2, uses the present continuous *be visiting* with the past tense *would*, would being the past tense of will.

See here: [When should I use would, would-be, will and will have?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have) (ELU)

In summary both examples, are a complete mishmash of tenses, so to compare meanings would be an exercise in futility.